# My post titles is getting mashed up with my blog title

Tags: title, plugin-all-in-one-seo

I installed the all in one seo pack plugin and after enabling it my post titles get "stuck" with my blog title without a space in the title.

As you can see the post title is: `******.blogg.no`
And my blog title is: `Sp**set Blogg`

The title is now `*******.blogg.noSp**set Blogg,` I can't figure out how I can get these to separated.

My all in one seo pack settings is`%post_title%` on the posts.

Comment: Disable all in one SEO pack and then take a look if it persists, if not then its something do with your SEO pack settings

Comment: I have disabled all in one SEO pack and the problem persists

Comment: In header.php it says: <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its documented.. [**heres a fix**](http://www.optimiseblog.co.uk/twenty-ten-theme-all-in-one-seo-pack-joined-no-space-issue/)

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 0):

It is either the SEO plugin or your template files

```
<?php 
wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' |'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); 
?>
```

Comment: I have disabled all in one SEO pack and the problem persists. I'll have a look in my template files.

Comment: In header.php it says: <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

Comment: Check my updated answer with my current use of this function

Comment: It didn't solve it. It only added "| blogtitle"